# simpleHtmlDom со своей строкой

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Кусок html-кода отправляю с другой страницы

```
$parse = $_POST['all_page'];
$parse ->find('input')
```

Пытаюсь получить значения, но получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/ххх.ru/public_html/subb/auto.php on line 111
```

Comment: сначала надо загрузить эту строку в xml парсер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, в порядке бреда поинтересуюсь: Не приходило в голову глянуть [маны](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) или, хотя бы, перевести сообщение?
Риторический вопрос, наверное.

Проблема в том, что до того, как работать с парсером, нужно его сначала проинициализировать и работать с объектом, который он вернёт.
Например так:

```
$parse = str_get_html($_POST['all_page']); // Parse the DOM from the string
$parse ->find('input'); // Get all 'input' elements
```